# junit как протестировать Filter?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Есть фильтр который добавляет хедер ко всем запросам

```
    @Component("xForwardedForAppenderFilter")
    public class XForwardedForAppenderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
      private static final String CLIENT_IP_HEADER = "X-Forwarded-For";
      private static final String FAKE_CLIENT_IP = "11.22.33.44";
    
      @Override
      protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @NonNull HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
          @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException
      {
        HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest) {
          @Override
          public String getHeader(String name) {
            if (CLIENT_IP_HEADER.equals(name) && StringUtils.isBlank(super.getHeader(name)))
              return FAKE_CLIENT_IP;
            return super.getHeader(name);
          }
    
          @Override
          public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
            if (CLIENT_IP_HEADER.equals(name) && !super.getHeaders(name).hasMoreElements())
              return Collections.enumeration(Collections.singleton(FAKE_CLIENT_IP));
            return super.getHeaders(name);
          }
        };
        filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, httpServletResponse);
      }
```

Написал следующий тест, но при вызове getHeader фильтр не срабатывает.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class XForwardedForAppenderFilterTest {
    private static final String CLIENT_IP_HEADER = "X-Forwarded-For";
    private static final String FAKE_CLIENT_IP = "11.22.33.44";

    @InjectMocks
    private XForwardedForAppenderFilter xForwardedForAppenderFilter;

    @Test
    public void doFilterInternal() throws ServletException, IOException {
        MockHttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        MockHttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        httpServletRequest.addHeader("test","12345");
        MockFilterChain filterChain = new MockFilterChain();
        xForwardedForAppenderFilter.doFilterInternal(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, filterChain);
        Assert.assertTrue(httpServletRequest.getHeader(CLIENT_IP_HEADER).equals(FAKE_CLIENT_IP));
        Assert.assertTrue(httpServletRequest.getHeaders(CLIENT_IP_HEADER).nextElement().equals(FAKE_CLIENT_IP));
    }
}
```

Как заставить фильтр запускаться в тесте?

Comment: Что в вашем понимании значит "не срабатывает"? `XForwardedForAppenderFilter. doFilterInternal()` - просто обычный метод, из обычного и ничем не примечательного java-класса.. И вы его точно также, без изыск вызываете его в своем юнит-тесте.. Тут либо метод таки выполняется(срабатывает), либо у вас вообще проект не собирается падая с какой-то ошибкой - третьего не дано..

Comment: getHeader возвращает null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы проверяете не тот объект `request`.

Фильтр у вас берет входящий `request`, заворачивает его в обертку, в которой дополнительный функционал, и вызывает следующий фильтр в цепочке уже с оберткой.

Так вот, вы в тесте проверяете входящий `request` (он у вас хранится в `httpServletRequest`), а нужно проверять, тот, который передается по цепочке дальше. Для этого у вас есть `MockFilterChain`, который как раз и нужен, чтоб сохранить этот новый `request`, чтоб его можно было проверить:

```
MockFilterChain filterChain = new MockFilterChain();
xForwardedForAppenderFilter.doFilterInternal(
     httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, filterChain);

ServletRequest request = filterChain.getRequest();
Assert.assertTrue(request.getHeader(CLIENT_IP_HEADER).equals(FAKE_CLIENT_IP));
Assert.assertTrue(request.getHeaders(CLIENT_IP_HEADER).nextElement().equals(FAKE_CLIENT_IP));
```

И еще, не используйте `assertTrue` для проверки равенства. При неравенстве, ошибка не покажет значений. Используйте `assertEquals`:

```
Assert.assertEquals(request.getHeader(CLIENT_IP_HEADER), FAKE_CLIENT_IP);
```

Comment: только нужно
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) filterChain.getRequest();